# Write multiple items to firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've written an android app using Firebase as the backend. My problem is only one item can be stored in Firebase and when I try to write more data it replaces the existing data. I want to write multiple bits and data and retrieve them in a list view or something.

My Code is below:

```
public class Capture_Meetings extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextAddress;
private EditText editDateTime;
private TextView textViewPersons;
private Button buttonSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture__meetings);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
    editDateTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDateTime);

    textViewPersons = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPersons);

    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating firebase object
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

            //Getting values to store
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();
            String DateTime = editDateTime.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating Person object
            final MeetingUser person = new MeetingUser();

            //Adding values
            person.setName(name);
            person.setAddress(address);
            person.setDateTime(DateTime);

            //Storing values to firebase
            ref.child("Person").setValue(person);


            //Value event listener for realtime data update
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
                {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Getting the data from snapshot
                        MeetingUser person = postSnapshot.getValue(MeetingUser.class);

                        //Adding it to a string
                        String string = "\n Name of School: "+person.getName()+"\n Date:"+ person.getDateTime()+"\nMeeting Notes: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

                        //Displaying it on textview
                        textViewPersons.setText(string);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Firebase documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) You can use the push method to append data to a node, which will have a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

in Firebase you can not store many items/values under one child. But, you can make as many childs (children) with a single value as you want. Just make childs with tags s.a. "address" and "name" with their respective values.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid overwriting of data we can use push() method in following way-

from your code -

```
ref.child("Person").setValue(person);
```

just put push() before setValue() method, that is -

```
ref.child("Person").push().setValue(person);
```

It will avoid overwriting and it will create a unique id for each data you store under the Person.